# Power BI DAX string to decimal/float/double

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to convert a string into a decimal number in Power BI using DAX. I have a column with the following string "PROCESS TOOK 16.26 S" so the aim is to create a new column with the string trimmed so the remaining text is only the time in seconds, i.e. "16.26" in this case.

To do so, I created a new column with the following DAX:

`TimeLenght = SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(APITime[Message],"PROCESS TOOK ", ""), " S","")`

This actually gives me the desired output ("16.26"). The problem comes when I try to convert this output into a decimal data type.

I tried `TimeLenght = VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(APITime[Message],"PROCESS TOOK ", ""), " S",""))`, `TimeLenght = CONVERT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(APITime[Message],"PROCESS TOOK ", ""), " S",""), DOUBLE)`, and changing the data type in the Column Tools tab, but all three end up with the following result: 1626.

Answer (score 0):

in my desktop, all three DAX formulas you showed work. I am not sure about the problem, but you can have a try with these two formulas below:

```
TimeLenght = 
FORMAT(
    SUBSTITUTE(
        SUBSTITUTE(APITime[Message],"PROCESS TOOK ", ""),
         " S",""),
00.00)
```

`

```
TimeLenght 2 = MID(APITime[Message],14,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank your all for answering. Turns out this issue has to do with the regional configuration of the computer (Windows).

I live in Mexico and we use "." as decimal separators and "," as thousands separators, but someone set Spain as the Country/Region when installing Windows.

Spain and most european countries use "," as decimal separators and "." as thousand separators. So I modified my DAX formula as follows:

```
TimeLenght = SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(APITime[Message],"PROCESS TOOK ", ""), " S",""),".",",")
```

Note: I changed the region in Windows configuration but this solved nothing. This issue also affects Power Bi Web.